# How can I setup a static IP address for my Debian Virtual Machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, static-ip

I have already set a static IP for a virtual machine in a private network in my school's laboratory. However, if I follow the same steps at home I cannot set a static IP for my Debian Virtual Machine.

My etc/network/interfaces file is configured like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.59
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Once I restart my machine, and after I type `ifconfig` in the terminal, I see that my IP address is 192.168.1.59, but I cannot `ping` any website, such as google.com. I get a message that reads 'unknown host google.com'.

What should I do to set a static IP address then?

I will thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: More information is required. Does it work with DHCP? What do you use for virtualization? Virtualbox? Your syntax looks correct.

Comment: Does you home network actually use that address range? Do you actually have a gateway that is reachable by that address? Currently your DNS configuration might be missing (in addition).

Comment: @MikaelKjær, What do you mean if it works with DHCP? If I understand correctly, by setting a static IP address, I am avoiding using DHCP. Otherwise, my file would have a line that reads `iface eth0 inet dhcp`.
And yes, I'm using Virtualbox.

Comment: @Seth, my gateway does have that IP address, and all my devices connected to my home network currently have an IP address such as 192.168.1.x

Comment: @Seth, I just checked the DNS configuration. That was the problem. All I had to do was add the final line dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254

Thank you very much.

Comment: He probably asked about DHCP because if the configuration was working with DHCP, it would be clear that the machine would be able to reach the internet if configured accordingly. That would limit errors like having the NIC configuration for the VM set to Host-Only or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The host was unreachable because no DNS server was specified.

The configuration file must be the following (as long as your gateway and nameserver have the same IP address)

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.59
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
```